# Securesocial in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, securesocial

When I try to set up eclipse with a project that depends on securesocial, I get this message:

Project 'xxx' is missing required Java project: 'securesocial'

I followed the advice of [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/vEyAnDL19M8)

Here's my Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.EclipsePlugin.EclipseKeys

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    override def settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
        EclipseKeys.skipParents in ThisBuild := false)

    val appName         = "XXX"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val ssDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.0.1",
      "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
    )

    val secureSocial = PlayProject(
        "securesocial", appVersion, ssDependencies, mainLang = SCALA, path = file("modules/securesocial")
    ).settings(
      resolvers ++= Seq(
        "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/",
        "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
      )
    )

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    // Only compile the bootstrap bootstrap.less file and any other *.less file in the stylesheets directory 
    def customLessEntryPoints(base: File): PathFinder = ( 
      (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "bootstrap.less") +++
      (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" / "bootstrap" * "responsive.less") +++ 
      (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" * "*.less")
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
      lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(customLessEntryPoints)
    ).dependsOn(secureSocial).aggregate(secureSocial)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, import the Secure Social module as a regular Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Add "app" folder of securesocial module to source build path of project in eclipse.